# Closed curve $\gamma$ such that least area of a surface with boundary $2\gamma$

Tags: algebraic-topology, curves, geometric-topology

What does the following statement mean? Any geometric intuition would be very helpful.

L.C. Young constructed a closed curve $\gamma$ in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that the least area of a surface with boundary $2\gamma$ is strictly less than twice of that with boundary $\gamma$.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02851262.pdf

The following paper says this in the first page
https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0101

I have no formal math background. What does $2\gamma$ mean? Any help in understanding this would be good.

Comment: I can't find the result in the paper you linked to. Could you please specify a page number?

Comment: I edited the question. That paper by Nie says this statement in the first paragraph.

Comment: The author of the arxiv paper states that $2\cdot \gamma$ is the curve $\gamma$ "traced twice",  and gives this source: L. C. Young, Some extremal questions for simplicial complexes V. The relative area of a
Klein bottle, Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo, Volume 12, Issue 3, September –
December 1963, pp. 257-274. Perhaps try looking there...

Comment: That is the same paper which I linked

Comment: @T.Harish: It isn't. You linked to paper number IV in that series. The source $[6]$ given in the sentence you quoted from the arxiv paper (without at first giving us the link to the arxiv paper -- why not?!), which Alexander cited, is paper number V in that series. So it's not surprising that I didn't find the result in the paper you linked to.

Comment: @joriki My bad, I was about to travel, so wanted to put the question up as quickly as possible and get an answer. I shall edit the question.